# Run-time Error '3061' Too few parameters. Expected 3

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I know this has been asked before, but the questions I have looked at are all a bit different. I am working on creating a temporary table, importing data, placing the data in an existing table, and deleting the temp table. Here is my code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim StrSql As String
Dim rst As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()

If DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = 'tblInfoLink'") = 1 Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblInfoLink"
    StrSql = "SELECT tblStaff.LastName, tblStaff.FirstName, tblStaff.Rank, tblStaff.PriPhone, " _
            & " tblStaff.SecPhone, tblStaff.HireDate INTO tblInfoLink " _
            & " FROM [\\Server\BE.accdb].tblStaff " _
            & " WHERE (((tblInfo.LastName)=[tblInfo].[LastName]) AND ((tblInfo.FirstName)=[tblInfo].[FirstName]) AND ((tblInfo.HireDate)=[tblInfo].[HireDate]));"
    db.Execute StrSql
ElseIf DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = 'tblInfoLink'") = 0 Then
    StrSql = "SELECT tblStaff.LastName, tblStaff.FirstName, tblStaff.Rank, tblStaff.PriPhone, " _
            & " tblStaff.SecPhone, tblStaff.HireDate INTO tblInfoLink " _
            & " FROM [\\Server\BE.accdb].tblStaff " _
            & " WHERE (((tblStaff.LastName)=[tblInfo].[LastName]) AND " _
            & " ((tblStaff.FirstName)=[tblInfo].[FirstName]) AND ((tblStaff.HireDate)=[tblInfo].[HireDate]));"
    db.Execute StrSql
End If

StrSql = "Update tblInfo Set PriPhone = Null, SecPhone = Null"
db.Execute StrSql

StrSql = "INSERT Into tblInfo (PriPhone, SecPhone) " _
        & " SELECT tblInfoLink.PriPhone, tblInfoLink.SecPhone " _
        & " FROM tblInfoLink " _
        & " WHERE (((tblInfoLink.LastName)=[tblInfo].[LastName]) AND " _
            & " ((tblInfoLink.FirstName)=[tblInfo].[FirstName]) AND ((tblInfoLink.HireDate)=[tblInfo].[HireDate]));"
db.Execute StrSql

'Delete Linked Tables
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblInfoLink"
```

As soon as I try and run this, I get the Run-time Error '3061' Too few parameters. Expected 3. When I hit debug the highligthed area is:

`db.Execute StrSql`

I know after the End If, everything works. It is literally the most important part of this that ISN'T working.

ANY ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try use `Debug.Print StrSql` or `MsgBox StrSql` before the line to check the query , I believe you will spot the problems

Comment: That just shows me the exact SQL statement I am making.

`SELECT LastName, FirstName, Rank, PriPhone, SecPhone, HireDate INTO tblOfcInfoLink FROM [\\Server\BE.accdb].tblStaff  WHERE (((tblStaff.LastName)=[tblInfo].[LastName]) AND  ((tblStaff.FirstName)=[tblInfo].[FirstName]) AND ((tblStaff.HireDate)=[tblInfo].[HireDate]));`

Comment: did you use `Debug.Print StrSql` ?

Comment: I'm assuming I did it right. I did that and then Ctrl+G when I hit debug and that's what is showed in the Immediate Window

Comment: @keongkenshih, I just made a couple edits and I am pretty certain the issue is in the WHERE statement.

Comment: Most likely case is that your selected field names do not match with what's required for the insertion. You have number of SQL statements here. Can you try to execute one at a time? Since you are running against Access db, please wrap your dates with `#`

Comment: What in the world is this supposed to mean: `WHERE (((tblInfo.LastName)=[tblInfo].[LastName]` ??

Comment: @bonCodigo - I kind of did that, I took the `WHERE` statement out of the `If` statement and that did the table creation, it worked exactly how I needed it to do minus the criteria that I wanted included.
When I took the `WHERE` out of the `if` statement, it hangs up at the same spot only on the `StrSql = "INSERT Into tblInfo (PriPhone, SecPhone) " _` a little further down the line. That's why I am thinking that it IS something with the `WHERE` criteria.
I forgot about the `#` for the date because I originally wasn't going to do dates, so thanks for that reminder.

Comment: @LocEngineer - As I started troubleshooting a bit, I realized I was approaching this wrong. First off, instead of `INSERT`, I need to do `UPDATE`. Here's the goal, I am pulling a list of approx 500 staff members from `tblStaff` (server) I am updating the primary and secondary phone numbers in `tblInfo` (local), which contains approx 75 of those 500 staff members. I want to search based on LastName, FirstName, AND HireDate. When all of these criteria are met, I want to put the phone number into `tblInfo` into THAT staff member's record.

Comment: I'm decent with VBA (not great by any means). However, SQL, I am a complete rookie. I can do enough to do what I need, but then there are some more advanced cases where I am WAY out of my comfort zone. This being one of them!

Comment: @S1naps1s - that's what I thought. Are the right side of the = in the Where clause supposed to be access form field values / textbox values?

Comment: `know after the End If, everything works. It is literally the most important part of this that ISN'T working.` : In such situations where most important part is not working, we usually say **nothing is working**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everyone know, I FINALLY got it.

```
Dim db As Database<br>
Dim StrSql As String<br>
Dim tblCount As Integer<br>

Const cstrPrompt As String = "Are you sure you want to start the import process? Yes/No"
If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set db = CurrentDb()`

'Link to Lt's Database to retrieve Phone Numbers

    StrSql = "UPDATE tblInfo SET PriPhone = Null, SecPhone = Null;"
    db.Execute StrSql

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblPhone"

    StrSql = "CREATE TABLE tblPhone " _
        & " (SSN CHAR, PriPhone CHAR (20), SecPhone CHAR(20));"
        db.Execute StrSql

     StrSql = "INSERT INTO tblPhone (SSN, PriPhone, SecPhone) " _
            & " SELECT ClockNbrId, PriPhone, SecPhone " _
            & " FROM [\\Server\BE.accdb].tblStaff; "
    db.Execute StrSql

StrSql = "UPDATE tblInfo INNER JOIN tblPhone ON tblInfo.SSN = tblPhone.SSN" _
    & " SET tblInfo.PriPhone = [tblPhone].[PriPhone], tblInfo.SecPhone = [tblPhone].[SecPhone] " _
    & " WHERE (((tblInfo.SSN)=[tblPhone].[SSN])); "
    db.Execute StrSql

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblPhone"

Const cstrPrompt2 As String = "The import process is complete"
If MsgBox(cstrPrompt2, vbOKOnly, "Import Complete!") = vbOK Then
    Me.ImportDel.Enabled = False
    Me.ImportDel.Caption = "Import Complete"

Exit_SyncStaff:
Set db = Nothing

Else
    Cancel = True
End If

End If`
```

Thank you all for your help. I wanted to post the solution so if there are issues in the future others can refer to this. It appeared as though my problem was the `INNER JOIN`. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have done some modifying over the last couple days. This is where I am now.

`Dim db As Database
Dim StrSql As String
Dim rst As Recordset`

```
Set db = CurrentDb()

'Link to Database to retrieve Phone Numbers
If DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = 'tblInfoLink'") = 1 Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblInfoLink"
    StrSql = "SELECT ClockNbrId, PriPhone, SecPhone INTO tblInfoLink " _
            & " FROM [\\Server\BE.accdb].tblStaff; "
    Debug.Print StrSql
    db.Execute StrSql

ElseIf DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = 'tblInfoLink'") = 0 Then
    StrSql = "SELECT ClockNbrId, PriPhone, SecPhone INTO tblInfoLink " _
            & " FROM [\\Server\BE.accdb].tblStaff; "
    Debug.Print StrSql
    db.Execute StrSql
End If

'Delete All Phone Numbers (Primary and Secondary) from tblInfo
StrSql = "Update tblInfo Set PriPhone = Null, SecPhone = Null"
db.Execute StrSql

'Update Phone Numbers of Current Staff
StrSql = "UPDATE tblInfo SET tblInfo.PriPhone = tblInfoLink.PriPhone" _
        & " WHERE tblInfoLink.ClockNbrId = tblInfo.SSN ; "
Debug.Print StrSql
db.Execute StrSql

'Delete Linked Table
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblInfoLink"
```

`Exit_SyncStaff:
    Set db = Nothing`

Basically this is what I want to happen.
I run the command, it nulls all current phone numbers, connects to the database on the server, collect all phone numbers (Primary and Secondary) and insert them into the row that contains the same SSN. I was able to start using the SSN as the only criteria needed to insert into that specific row, rather than first name, last name, and hire date. I hope this makes sense.